# Objective c - App crash when thread delegate doesn't exist

Tags: objective-c

I have an App that loads table images on the background. When I enter to the screen, it starts loading the images and all works good. But when I go back to the previous screen while images are being loaded my App crashes. I assume it happens since objective c is trying to call a delegate in a class instance that is no longer exists. Is there a way of solving this issue?

Comment: There is no way to give you any useful answer without code.

Comment: I am not sure code can help here much, and the whole code has many rows that can confuse. The question is quite general: what can you do in case you perform some asynchronous action and set a delegate as "self". Now, when you leave the screen, the class instance no longer exists, so the App crashes (when asynchronous action ends and would like to call the delegate function).

Answer (score 0):

Without a code there is one thing I can think of:

In order to make your instance exist, your delegation property needs to be typed as strong :

`@property (nonatomic, strong) DelegateObjectType *delegate;`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want it to exist. There is the master screen and the detail screen. The detail screen it created each time the user navigates there, but can leave the screen before all images are loaded.

Comment: Are you sure you should destroy your detail view every time you navigate from there? You can load another data to an existing view...

Comment: I don't have to destroy it, but currently this is managed automatically by Objective c and Storyboards. It is a Master and detail. When I move back from the detailed to the master I assume it destroys the detail.

Comment: Of course you don't destroy it explicitly. If you are not declaring it as strong it's been destroyed.